# When does the day window take effect for API Gateway usage plans (1000/day)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-key

I have configured my API gateway with API key that has usage plan attached to it so that caller with the given API key can only make 1000 requests/day.

When I configure it for 1000 requests per day, does it mean it can make 1000 requests in any given 24 hour window? or It can make 1000 requests from 12 am untill 11:59 pm UTC in a given day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one day UTC, so 1000 requests from 12am until 11:59pm UTC